# How to access to PHP function on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a php file in my file manager that shows a search bar on a Wordpress page, which will show the items in the database as a suggestion, calling another php script that is located in the same folder. I call it like this:

```
$.get("backend-search.php", {term: inputVal}).done(function(data){
// Display the returned data in browser
resultDropdown.html(data);
```

But when I type something in the search box, it shows a GET 404 error in the console and nothing appear.
Also, if I try to access the php function directly like "www.example.com/backend-search.php" or "www.example.com/index.php/backend-search.php", Wordpress shows that the page doesn't exist.

How can I access then that php file from another php code or just inside Wordpress?

Thank you!

Comment: Is `backend-search.php` in the same directory as the script that's calling it?

Comment: Yes, both are inside my child theme folder

Comment: Should they be in different directories? @El_Vanja

Comment: They should be wherever you see fit to place them. I was only asking because to call it like `$.get("backend-search.php"` they need to be in the same folder. Not sure what further issue might be causing this, I haven't got a lot of experience with Wordpress.

Comment: yeah I see, I suppose it has to be something related with the routes but not sure at all, thank you anyway